# What's the best way to handle(or alternative) the use case of creating multiple table from single model in Django

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I have a use-case where a client registers to my platform and I have to give them a separate table in a database using a common model in Django.

Although I have been able to create multiple tables from a single model on runtime, I don't think its the best solution to the problem and I have seen some issues with it on my testing like when doing migrations of the model and Django admin pages, etc.

Are there any other alternatives to this problem? How do other companies handle such issues?

Comment: The term you're looking for is "multi-tenancy" or "multitenant"

Comment: ohh, thanks I will look into it

Comment: You don't need to create a separate table for each client. There are other techniques to achieving multi-tenancy. This document - https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-multi-tenant/en/latest/index.html - describes them elaborately.

Comment: ok, i will look into it